# Webcam image mirrored

Tags: webcam

Hi I'm using Kubuntu and the webcam image in all applications (skype, teams) are mirrored. Therefore all text are reversed (see [Teams webcam settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xanDY.png)). I tried installing cheese and other application, in which I can flip the image but no effect on MS teams or Skype.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1390499/edit) the question to add the information about 1. model/brand of your computer, and 2. the version of Kubuntu. Is this issue present in other operating systems, like Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like normal to everyone.

> The default setting in Skype is that you are seeing your own image as mirrored, while your contacts are seeing normal image. This is how Skype is designed to work.

from Skype community

Microsoft likes a weird design.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that the image is not reversed for my interlocutor.

Comment: I would assume this is also the case with Zoom?